# How can I solve this error TypeError: Users is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> How can I solve this error TypeError: Users is not a function

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Users = require('../models/user');

router.post('/signup', function(req, res){
    // res.send('Ok');
    var name = req.body.name;
    var surname = req.body.surname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var confirm_password = req.body.confirm_password;

    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('surname', 'Surname is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email address is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email address').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('confirm_password', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.json({status: errors})
    }else{
        var newUser = new Users({
            name:name,
            surname:surname,
            email:email,
            username:username,
            password:password
        })
        Users.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err){ throw err};
            console.log(user);
        });
        res.json({status:"success"})
    }
})
router.get('/signin', function(req, res){
    res.send('Sure');
})

module.exports = router;
```

> Im trying to insert a new user into my mongodb, but I keep getting an error that User is not a function, I have my above code is in my routes folder and the below code is my schema

```
        var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

    var usersSchema = new Schema({
        name:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        surname:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        email:{
            type:Number
        },
        username:{
            type:Number
        },
        password:{
            type:Number
        },
        create_date:{
            type:Date,
            default:Date.now
        }
    })

    var Users =  mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);

    module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
        // hashing the passwords
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
                newUser.password = hash;
                 newUser.save(callback);
            })
        })

    }
```

Comment: Hi Mlindos. Where do you get the error? You have references Users in many places

Answer (score 2):

You must export Users model.
Read [mongoose guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
})


usersSchema.statics.createUser = function (newUser, callback) {
    ...
}


module.exports =  mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema)
```